# How to work with chained function in Ubuntu

Tags: bash

I am trying execute the following script, but can't figure out how to pass a value as arguments which i have already got from another function's argument. Answer with explanation will be more appriciated as i am a beginner in bash scripts.

```
function execute{
    task = $1
    servername = $2
    $task $servername
}


function installDependency{
    servername = $1
    sshpass -p password ssh servername 'bash -s' < install_dependency.sh
}


function removeDependency{
    servername = $1
    sshpass -p password ssh servername 'bash -s' < remove_dependency.sh
}


execute remove_dependency server1
```

I am getting the following error:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `task=$1'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid the space characters for a declaration

```
servername="$1"
```

instead of

```
servername = $1
```

---

```
function removeDependency {
    servername="$1"
    sshpass -p password ssh servername 'bash -s' < remove_dependency.sh
}


function execute {
    task="$1"
    servername="$2"
    "$task" "$servername"
}


function installDependency {
    servername="$1"
    sshpass -p password ssh servername 'bash -s' < install_dependency.sh
}

execute "removeDependency" "server1"
```

Comment: way much better after some edits :-)